# How passing variable as first parameter to add_action() work?

Tags: wordpress, action

I understand how actions work, something like this:

`do_action()` invokes all functions hooked to the action hook

`add_action()` hook the functions which we want to be invoked in some moment to an action hook but it won't invoked till `do_action` work

When i read in wordpress code for example  `add_submenu_page` function there is something like this:

```
 $hookname = get_plugin_page_hookname( $menu_slug, $parent_slug);
    if (!empty ( $function ) && !empty ( $hookname ))
        add_action( $hookname, $function );
```

My question is: what is the use of `$hookname` in `add_action()` and how to invoke the function ?

Answer (score 0):

If you define a function:

```
function my_function() {
    // Code here
}
```

And then make it an action using:

```
add_action( 'my_hook_name', 'my_function' );
```

It will be called whenever there is a call like:

```
do_action( 'my_hook_name' );
```

But the 'do_action()' is different to calling the function directly because it will also call any other functions that have been added to that hook. If you look at the docs for WordPress hooks you will see that there is a way to control the order of the actions when the 'do_action()' is called.